# Rust: Lifetime of String from file

Tags: file, io, rust

I'm trying to read in some external GLSL code into Rust.  The reading works properly, but I run into a lifetime issue in the final expression (in the Ok(_) branch)

error: `s` does not live long enough

```
fn read_shader_code(string_path: &str) -> &str {
    let path = Path::new(string_path);
    let display = path.display();

    let mut file = match File::open(&path) {
        Err(why) => panic!("Couldn't open {}: {}", display, Error::description(&why)),
        Ok(file) => file,
    };

    let mut s = String::new();
    match file.read_to_string(&mut s) {
        Err(why) => panic!("couldn't read {}: {}", display, Error::description(&why)),
        Ok(_) => &s,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string bound to "s" will be deallocated once the function ends ("s" goes out of scope), so you cannot return a reference to its contents outside the function.
The best way is to return the string itself:

```
fn read_shader_code(string_path: &str) -> String {
    let path = Path::new(string_path);
    let display = path.display();

    let mut file = match File::open(&path) {
        Err(why) => panic!("Couldn't open {}: {}", display, Error::description(&why)),
        Ok(file) => file,
    };

    let mut s = String::new();
    match file.read_to_string(&mut s) {
        Err(why) => panic!("couldn't read {}: {}", display, Error::description(&why)),
        Ok(_) => s,
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried this actually, and took the reference to the returned String.  It works, but is there any other solution that would return an &str?

Comment: Well.. you can create the string outside the function and pass it as parameter, so you will have no lifetime problems, but you cannot return a reference to something who live only in the function outside of it. fn read_shader_code(string_path: &str, &mut String buffer) -> &str {} Use buffer for the line buffer instead of s.